# Azure WebApp (WebSite) Load Balancer Probe

Tags: azure, iis, devops

Is there a way to configure azure website load balancer probe to check a specific path?

Context:
I'm converting a Cloud Service to a WebApp (website). In the service definition of the cloud service, the load balancer probe is configured to check a specific path (example "/healthcheck").

I see that azure webapps uses IIS extension "Application Request Routing", which is the only thing that looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Azure websites internally looks at the health of the whole server, and if the server is not healthy it will not receive requests.

To provide more details: the Azure Website load balancer uses a load index to route requests. The load index is calculated based on the resource load of the worker servers. It also uses some called an ARR affinity cookie which keeps sessions "sticky" i.e. if a client is being served requests by a particular worker, subsequent requests will be served by that worker.

Note that it is possible to configure an explicit path to check for the load balancer using IaaS, i.e. Azure VMs.

(Source: I'm a dev on the Azure Web Apps team)

Comment: But if the sticked worker is too loaded or down or it reports a constant http 500 how can you tell if you are only looking at the physical side of the app? It would be awesome if I could configure thru web.config